# Prove that $ax=0$ has a nonzero solution in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $ax=1$ has no solution.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $a\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Prove that $ax=0$ has a nonzero solution in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $ax=1$ has no solution.

$\textbf{My proof (just one way)}$:

($\Rightarrow$)
Suppose $a\neq 0$ and that $\exists u, u \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. This implies that $n|au$. Now I will try to prove that $gcd(a,n) \neq 1$. Suppose that $gcd(a,n)=1$, then $n\nmid a$ and $a\nmid n$. Since $n|au$, but $n\nmid a$ and $a\nmid n$, it follows that $n|u$, but then $u \equiv 0$ (mod n). This means that $u$ is a zero solution in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Contradiction.

Also, I know the following theorem:
Let $a$ and $n$ be integers with $n>1$. Then $gcd(a,n)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the equation $ax=1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Since $gcd(a,n) \neq 1$, from the theorem above it follows that $ax=1$ has no solution in in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

$\textbf{My question:}$

Is my reasoning correct? Also, I would appreciate if somebody showed my the second part of the proof, i.e. $(\Leftarrow)$, or gave me some hints.

I have tried to think in a similar way: $ax=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has no solution $\Rightarrow$ $gcd(a,n) \neq 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists d$ that $d|a$ and $d|n$, but it does not lead anywhere, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two facts:

1) $gcd(a,n)=1\iff ax=1$ has solution in $\Bbb Z_n$.

2) $gcd(a,n)>1\iff ax=0$ has solution in $\Bbb Z_n$.

The two are mutually exclusive and include all situations.

To prove 1) on uses [Bezout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) and the fact that $ax=1$ in $\Bbb Z_n$ is equivalent to $ax+ny=1$ in $\Bbb Z$.

To prove 2) note that if $a=dr$ and $n=ds$ with $d>1$ then $as=0$ in $\Bbb Z_n$ and conversely if $ax=0$ in $\Bbb Z_n$ then $ax=kn$ in $\Bbb Z$ and $gcd(a,n)>1$.

Answer (score 1):

More simply: if ax=0 and xb=1 then a=axb=0b=0. For the converse the pigeon holes principle gives you a way...